# how to select multiple row values

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to select the all rows from the table where `s_id=id`

But the problem I am having is that there are array of id's sent from form

I have a form where:

```
$s_id = intval($_GET['s_id']);
$cid = intval($_GET['cid']);
foreach($s_id as $s_id) {
    $query="SELECT skillname FROM skills WHERE s_id='$s_id' AND cid='$cid'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<p name="eval"><?php echo $row['skillname']?><input type='text' size='5' name='eval'>Evaluate on 5 </p>

<?php }
```

the problem with the above code is that how can i select skill name for multiple `s_id`
Waiting for your answers 
Thanx in advance

Comment: `WHERE s_id IN('".join("','",$s_id)."')`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid can you elaborate iam even getting error saying that invalid argument in foreach

Comment: If `$s_id` is array of ids that you need to comapare with `s_id` column then you don't need the foreach loop just use `IN()` in your query

Comment: Using `mysql_` functions is generally a bad idea — you should consider migrating to `mysqli_` or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

What is your HTML code?
I don't understand how you can iterate through int value

```
$s_id = intval($_GET['s_id']);
....
foreach($s_id as $s_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You COULD do this:

```
$s_id = intval($_GET['s_id']);
$cid = intval($_GET['cid']);
$query="SELECT skillname FROM skills WHERE s_id IN('" . implode(',', $s_id) . "') AND cid='$cid'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
[...]
```

BUT! This is dangerous. You must filter Get and Post vars befor getting in contact with SQL. Keep it in mind http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection

Comment: if use the above code i am getting an error
      Warning: implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: try this: `$s_id = intval($_GET['s_id']); print_r($s_id);` check if the $s_id is realy an array..